# Find all rows that have a value in a certain column that occurs more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a database with two columns, an id (bigint) and text (text).  I want to find all rows in the database that have an id that occurs in more than one row.  How could I do that?

Example:

```
1; foo  
2; bar 
3; baz
2; fubar
4; blah
3; bleh
```

Desired output:

```
2; bar 
2; fubar
3; baz
3; bleh
```

I'm quite new to SQL.  I have a notion that I want something along the lines of

```
SELECT id,text FROM mytable ORDER BY id ASC;
```

But I have no idea how to eliminate the rows where the id is unique. I need essentially the opposite of `SELECT DISTINCT`.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think there is a simple way of doing it, without using nested queries.
Have you tried using 'GROUP BY' and 'HAVING' to display the rows with duplicate IDs?

'SELECT COUNT(*), id, text FROM my_Table GROUP BY id HAVING count(id) > 1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select id, text
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: Is t here supposed to be the name of my table?  I'm confused about the `t` outside the close paren on the third line

Comment: @PurpleVermont `t` in the third line is a name for the subquery in parentheses. You can change it to any name. The name of your table goes to the `from` part instead of `table`.

Comment: Ah, thanks, I was confused since it was the same variable as the name of the table inside the parens.  Also I think `FROM TABLE` is wrong, and we just need `FROM`, right?  Why does the subquery need/get a name if it is never referenced?

Comment: Oh, ok, so all the `t`s are in fact supposed to be the same, and `table` is the name of my table? I obviously need to learn more about window functions, because I'm having trouble making sense if this, if the name given outside the parens is also being referenced inside the parents.

Comment: `table` is intended to be your table name.

Comment: Both this and @rfusca's query below run out of memory when running on my 92K line database via PGAdmin III.  (It has a few extra columns, and the text field is filled with large paragraphs of text.)  Am I just using the wrong client for this type of work, or is there something I could do to lessen the memory load?

Comment: @PurpleVermont . . . These queries are not particularly memory intensive.  You should check your memory setting for Postgres.  If the problem persists, ask on dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
WITH more_than_one AS (SELECT id,count(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY id HAVING count(*) > 1)
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN more_than_one ON table1.id = more_than_one.id;
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was getting close to your AS clause, but I don't think I'd have gotten the whole thing without your help.

Comment: With window functions the query can be done in a single scan. Your current query does 2 scans and a join.